# Creating a standalone java client of salesforce chatter using rest Api

Tags: rest-api, chatter, oauth2, httprequest

**EDIT** I am struggling to add the  correct formatting to the code post below. if someone can edit this question and apply the proper formatting to code, i would appreciate it.

I am fairly new to salesforce and as a required to our project in have to create a standalone java client for chatter. I have already developed clients for reading, writing data to salesforce custom objects using WSDL from apex classes.
Since Chatter is REST based, i  am not able to integrate it. I am facing problem with generating the oAuth access tokens. When i am making calls to the  https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token i am getting error message as connection refused.
Most of the tutorial i checked get access token using cUrl but i want it all to be done through a JAVA application.

I am behind a corporate firewall and have configured my proxy accordingly. Here is the code that i have developed.

```
package com.chatter.sf;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;


import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy;
import org.apache.http.client.params.HttpClientParams;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class SfChatter {






    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void oAuthSessionProvider(String loginHost, String username,
            String password, String clientId, String secret)
            throws HttpException, IOException, ParseException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException, ServiceException, SOAPException 
    {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        // Set up an HTTP client that makes a connection to REST API.
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams params = client.getParams();
       HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(params, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
        params.setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,100000);

        // Set the SID.
        System.out.println("Logging in as " + username + " in environment " + loginHost);

       //String baseUrl = loginHost;


         String baseUrl = loginHost + "/services/oauth2/token";

        HttpPost oauthPost = new HttpPost(baseUrl);





        // The request body must contain these 5 values.
        List<BasicNameValuePair> parametersBody = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();



       parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
       parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
       parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
       parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", clientId));
       parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", secret));
        oauthPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametersBody, HTTP.UTF_8));

        // Execute the request.
        System.out.println("POST " + baseUrl + "...\n");
        HttpResponse response=null;
        try{
         response= client.execute(oauthPost);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception is= "+e.getMessage());
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Map<String, String> oauthLoginResponse = (Map<String, String>)
            parser.parse(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        System.out.println("OAuth login response");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : oauthLoginResponse.entrySet()) 
        {
            System.out.println(String.format("  %s = %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        System.out.println("");

        // Get user info.
        String userIdEndpoint = oauthLoginResponse.get("id");
        String accessToken = oauthLoginResponse.get("access_token");
        List<BasicNameValuePair> qsList = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        qsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_token", accessToken));
        String queryString = URLEncodedUtils.format(qsList, HTTP.UTF_8);
        HttpGet userInfoRequest = new HttpGet(userIdEndpoint + "?" + queryString);
        HttpResponse userInfoResponse = client.execute(userInfoRequest);
        Map<String, Object> userInfo = (Map<String, Object>)
            parser.parse(EntityUtils.toString(userInfoResponse.getEntity()));
        System.out.println("User info response");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : userInfo.entrySet()) 
        {
            System.out.println(String.format("  %s = %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        System.out.println("");

        // Use the user info in interesting ways.
        System.out.println("Username is " + userInfo.get("username"));
        System.out.println("User's email is " + userInfo.get("email"));
        Map<String, String> urls = (Map<String, String>)userInfo.get("urls");
        System.out.println("REST API url is " + urls.get("rest").replace("{version}", "31.0"));
    }




public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, HttpException, IOException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException, ServiceException, SOAPException    
{
     String loginhost="https://login.salesforce.com";


    String username="balaji.sozharajan@wipro.com";
 String password="*****";
 String client_id="3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp5EMJiZPLQ0WUTN2aYG5RxGBlTZsB8xM97W4ehLHQKYMGTxSIAR6SGVsjLm3a.opMthTIE2";
 String client_key="************";



    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "proxy2.wipro.com");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "80");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "sh265993");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "*********");


 oAuthSessionProvider(loginhost,username,password, client_id, client_key);

}



}
```

I have spent enire week finding a solution but still haven't found a way out. Any solution or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Here is the stacktrace after executing the code given by @Mohith

```
Logging in as balaji.sozharajan@wipro.com in environment https://login.salesforce.com
POST https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token...

Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:524)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at com.wipro.coe.Action.TestCallout.oAuthSessionProvider(TestCallout.java:54)
    at com.wipro.coe.Action.TestCallout.main(TestCallout.java:98)
```

Comment: To format when editing, select the code and click the {} button.

Comment: based on the stack trace, your code is not trying to connect via a proxy, so you need to revisit that part of the code.

Comment: there doesn't appear to be any code in your example that is configuring the use of a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation link is below for oauth using Java client .

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/code_sample_auth_oauth.htm

```
public static void oAuthSessionProvider(String loginHost, String username,
    String password, String clientId, String secret)
    throws HttpException, IOException {
// Set up an HTTP client that makes a connection to REST API.
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams params = client.getParams();
HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(params, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
params.setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 30000);

// Set the SID.
System.out.println("Logging in as " + username + " in environment " + loginHost);
String baseUrl = loginHost + "/services/oauth2/token";
// Send a post request to the OAuth URL.
HttpPost oauthPost = new HttpPost(baseUrl);
// The request body must contain these 5 values.
List<BasicNameValuePair> parametersBody = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", clientId));
parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", secret));
oauthPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametersBody, HTTP.UTF_8));

// Execute the request.
System.out.println("POST " + baseUrl + "...\n");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(oauthPost);
int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
Map<String, String> oauthLoginResponse = (Map<String, String>)
    JSON.parse(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
System.out.println("OAuth login response");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : oauthLoginResponse.entrySet()) 
{
    System.out.println(String.format("  %s = %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
System.out.println("");

// Get user info.
String userIdEndpoint = oauthLoginResponse.get("id");
String accessToken = oauthLoginResponse.get("access_token");
List<BasicNameValuePair> qsList = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
qsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_token", accessToken));
String queryString = URLEncodedUtils.format(qsList, HTTP.UTF_8);
HttpGet userInfoRequest = new HttpGet(userIdEndpoint + "?" + queryString);
HttpResponse userInfoResponse = client.execute(userInfoRequest);
Map<String, Object> userInfo = (Map<String, Object>)
    JSON.parse(EntityUtils.toString(userInfoResponse.getEntity()));
System.out.println("User info response");
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : userInfo.entrySet()) 
{
    System.out.println(String.format("  %s = %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
System.out.println("");

// Use the user info in interesting ways.
System.out.println("Username is " + userInfo.get("username"));
System.out.println("User's email is " + userInfo.get("email"));
Map<String, String> urls = (Map<String, String>)userInfo.get("urls");
System.out.println("REST API url is " + urls.get("rest").replace("{version}", "31.0"));
}
```

> The above code uses the Apache HttpClient library which may be downloaded from http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have posted the error stacktrace i got after running the code provided by you. I am getting connection refused error.
 I have given login host as https://login.salesforce.com

Comment: Can you come out of your network and try this .Expecting its proxy thats refusing your connection

Comment: I have exposed some apex classes as webservices and am able to consume them with the same proxy settings. so i dont think that is the issue here.